# D3: passing object in style method is not working

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3 for the exercise. However, I am having trouble passing an object to the `.style()` method:

```
var myStyles = [
  '#268BD2',
  '#BD3613',
  '#D11C24',
  '#C61C6F',
  '#595AB7',
  '#2176C7'
];
```

This below piece of code is working

```
d3.selectAll('.item') 
  .data(myStyles)
  .style('background',function(d){return d});
```

But none of the below two code pieces are working

```
d3.selectAll('.item')
  .data(myStyles)
  .style({'background':function(d){return d}});

d3.selectAll('.item')
  .data(myStyles)
  .style({'color':'white','background':function(d){return d}});
```

Please explain what is wrong here.

Comment: Whats wrong is that selection.style() doesnt accept objects. https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_style

Comment: refer this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/K8VR-2pc1Sc

Answer (score 6):

You can apply objects in styles and attributes by using `d3-selection-multi`.

First, you have to reference the mini library:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you have to use `styles`, not `style`:

```
.styles({'color':'white','background':function(d){return d}});
```

You can see the code working in this fiddle, in which I'm using an object to set the `styles`: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/o54rtrqc/1/

For attributes, use `attrs` instead of `attr`.

Here is the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/blob/master/README.md#selection_attrs).

Comment: the last piece of code is working in codepen.io but not in my local machine: same has been explain on lynda.com as well, how its working on lynda and codepen but not on my local machine

Answer (score -1):

I'm also working through the Lynda.com course.  Here's an example of the "Binding data to the DOM" exercise using D3 version 4: 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NinoLopezWeb/tn5bp8cv/)

HTML:

```
    <!--
Added these two scripts:
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
-->

<div class="container">
  <h2>D3 Graphic</h2>
  <section id="chart">
    <div class="item">Darth Vader</div>
    <div class="item">Luke Skywalker</div>
    <div class="item">Han Solo</div>
    <div class="item">Obi-Wan Kenobi</div>
    <div class="item">Chewbacca</div>
    <div class="item">Boba Fett</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myStyles = [{
          width: 200,
          color: '#A57706'
        }, {
          width: 300,
          color: '#BD3613'
        }, {
          width: 150,
          color: '#D11C24'
        }, {
          width: 350,
          color: '#C61C6F'
        }, {
          width: 400,
          color: '#595AB7'
        }, {
          width: 250,
          color: '#2176C7'
}];

d3.selectAll('.item')
      .data(myStyles)
      .styles({
        'color': 'white',
        'background': function(d) {
          return d.color;
        },
        width: function(d) {
          return d.width + 'px';
        }
 })
```